# Select active item in an option box

Tags: html, twig, html-select

i've a problem with a "select" in a mobile versione of my site.
This is the code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectGift">
    {% for category in rewards_categories %}
            <option id="{{category.tag}}" class=" BarCategory Bar{{category.tag}}" value="/xxxx/{{ category.id }}/{{ category.categoryName}}">
                {{category.categoryName}}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

How can you see i'm using Twig extension in my template :)
The problem is that when i change option the redirect works but will not change the active list item , is always the first..

This is my JS code:

```
$('#selectGift').bind('change', function () {
var url = $(this).val();
window.location = url;
$(this).find('option:selected').addClass('active'); });
```

what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:selected` instead of `:active`

```
var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
```

Comment: Doing this I 'm going to SEARCH which elem has focus . I need to set as active the element that I selected..

Comment: I tried , but the item is not set as active. By controlling the Inspector I'm noticing that none of the four elements in the list has the ACTIVE -class ...

Comment: Did you do like this ? `$(this).find('option:selected').addClass('active')`